# How to connect to telegram api from telegram.link module?

Tags: node.js, api, telegram

I am using [telegram.link](https://github.com/enricostara/telegram.link/) for implementing telegram methods in node.js and working with my telegram account by sending and receiving messages.
but when I want to connect to telegram server as follow:

```js
  1 app = require("telegram.link")()
  2 client = app.createClient({
  3   id: 48820
  4   hash: '0028ba7cd67b8e9e487f7700cc4760e9'
  5   version: '1.0.0'
  6   lang: 'en'
  7 }, app.TEST_PRIMARY_DC, (ex) ->
  8   if !ex
  9     console.log 'ok'
 10     client.contacts.getContacts (err, result) ->
 11       console.log result
 12   else
 13     console.log 'Not ok'
 14 )   
 15 
 16 dc = client.getDataCenters()
 17 
 18 cosole.log dc
```

but when I want run this this error appear in my console
`[ERROR] Thu, 05 May 2016 16:19:41 GMT  telegram-link Client is not yet ready!`
What do you think about this error?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call `getDataCenters()`method before the connection has been stablished, i.e. you must make your call *inside* the callback of createClient, just before the call to `client.contacts.getContacts`